# Xamarin Set Image Source Programmatically

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin

I would like to set source of my image object programmatically in Xamarin. I have a text file and it has more than 200 file names. I read it line by line. So see what i want to do (not in Xamarin.Forms)

```
string[] MyFileNames = new string[] { };
MyFileNames = ReadedTextFileVariable.Split(System.Environment.NewLine);
ImageObject.ImagePath = MyFileNames[2]; //its an example. i want to put a string path. uri is not working
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is this `ImageObject` of yours, is it like an `ImageView`?

Comment: Exactly it is an ImageView

Comment: Then you can use `SetImageUri` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri)

Comment: I tried but its not working here an example of what i used
`ImageObject.SetImageURI(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(MyFileNames[2]));`